# Onclick Navigation

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="drp" value="maindrp" name="maindrp">
        <option>Select Categories</option>
        <option id="vhc" value="mainvhc">Vehicles</option>
        <option id="re" value="mainre">Real Estate</option>
        <option id="pt" value="mainpt">Pets</option>
        <option id="el" value="mainel">Electronics</option>
        <option id="cl" value="maincl">Clothing&Jewerly</option>
        <option id="co" value="mainco">Computers&Network</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="msc">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" id="go" onclick= "go();">
```

```
function go() { 
    if (document.getElementById("vhc")) { 
        window.location="vehicles.php"; 
    }else if (document.getElementById("re")) { 
        window.location="realestate.php"; } }
```

I want to navigate from selected item from drop down via button on click function.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you need to refine your question so we can help you, ie where are you navigating to, whats the url, what is your `go()` function

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: What do you need help with?  What *exactly* are you stuck on?

Comment: function go() {
            if (document.getElementById("vhc")) {
                window.location="vehicles.php";
                
            }else if (document.getElementById("re")) {
                window.location="realestate.php";
            }
         
        }  I have tried this but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need the value of `<select>` tag

```
function go(){
  var sel = document.getElementById('drp').value; // get value of <select>
  if(sel=='mainvhc')
    window.location.href='vehicles.php';
  ...
}
```

Comment: Definitely YES!!Thanks very much.